# Set-AzBatchPool starttask resourcefiles A constructor was not found Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSResourceFile

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-batch

I'm trying to set Azure Batch pool start task via powershell and Az module . Need to set ReosurceFiles but cannot create object for it `System.Collections.Generic.IList[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSResourceFile]`

New-AzBatchResourceFile - is not applicable because it creates Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSResourceFile object type

And when I'm trying to use I catch this error:

> Exception setting "ResourceFiles": "Cannot convert the "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSResourceFile" value of type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSResourceFile" to type
> "System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSResourceFile]"."
> At line:1 char:1
> $StartTask.ResourceFiles = $file
>
> ```
>    CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
>    FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
> ```

Here is full PSell code:

```
#Set Pool settings
$StartTask = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSStartTask
$UserIdentity = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSAutoUserSpecification -ArgumentList @("Task", "Admin")
$task= "/bin/sh -c `"~/blob2.sh $adadmin $publickey $accountName $accountKey $containerName`""
$StartTask.CommandLine = "$task"
$StartTask.MaxTaskRetryCount = 2
$StartTask.WaitForSuccess = $true
$StartTask.UserIdentity = $UserIdentity
$file = New-AzBatchResourceFile -HttpUrl "https://$accountName.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/blob2.sh" -FilePath "blob2.sh"
$StartTask.ResourceFiles = $file
$Pool.StartTask = $StartTask
Set-AzBatchPool -Pool $Pool -BatchContext $ctx
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I cannot modify the ResourceFiles property of the start task, no matter what i do.

Answer (score -1):

You could try thin in the above code :

```
$files = @()
$file = New-AzBatchResourceFile -HttpUrl "https://$accountName.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/blob2.sh" -FilePath "blob2.sh"
$files += $file
$StartTask.ResourceFiles = $files
```

Explanation, `$files` is a generic list to which I am adding the `$file` of type  `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSResourceFile`

Comment: This does not seem to work; The type ResourceFiles is expecting is a generic List with a generic type of PSResourceFile - It doesn't accept the genric object[] that @() generates.